# Xcode iPhone Time picker

Tags: iphone, ios4, uidatepicker

I'm trying to set up an NSArray class for a time picker, I was wondering if I could use a `UIDatePicker` and just import the NSArray?

This is what I have for code:

```
- (IBAction)showActionTime:(id)sender {
    NSString *title2 = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ? @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" : @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" ;
    UIActionSheet *actSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                               initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", title2, NSLocalizedString(@"Please Select A Time", @"")]
                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"I've Made My Choice", nil];
    [actSheet showInView:self.view];
    UIPickerView *timePicker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [timePicker setTag: time1];
    //timePicker.
    [actSheet addSubview:time1];
    [timePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(updateTimeLabel:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actSheet release];
}


- (void)updateTimeLabel:(UIActionSheet *) actSheet{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    NSArray *times = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"8:00-11:00",@"2:00-5:00",nil];
    UIPickerView *timePicker2 = (UIPickerView *) [actSheet viewWithTag:time1];
    [times release];


    //[formatter release];; 
    //UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date" message:selectedDate delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    //label1.text = msg;
    //[dateFormatter release];

    //[alert show];
    //[alert release];
    //[msg release];
}
```

But it doesn't even try to load the ActionSheet to begin with.It just crashes immediately. What could possibly be the problem?

*UPDATE:

Here is one of my warnings:

@implementation AppointmentController and the warning is "Incomplete Implementation"

and on this line:

```
[timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTimeLabel)
```

I'm getting "Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to stay on top of selecting correct answers so people are motivated to help you.

Comment: Is there an error in the console? If yes what does it say?

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: Moshe, No errors. It does have some warnings, but the compiler accepts everything and builds. Radek Pro-Grammer, this is being built in Xcode.

Comment: Also if it helps, I'm using Xcode 4.

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings.  Resolve them one-by-one.  If you don't know how, include the warnings in the question.  The crash is most likely caused by the addTarget line resulting in "unrecognized selector" (you should be able to see the message in the console).  There are a few other errors in the code including the one gkchristopher mentions.

Comment: (with respects to posting rules), should I create another post with those warnings, if nobody else has done so?

Comment: No, edit your Question and add the warnings there.

Answer (score 0):

Macfan9000,

What is time1?

And why are you adding it as a subview?

My guess is you mean to use `[actSheet addSubview:timePicker];`

Comment: time1 is the setTag value we defined ( #define time1 100 ) . I just tried to change it to [actSheet addSubview:timePicker]; and it still died, for the datepicker I did before this timepicker It was a subview